# Why the boxes in an inline formating context was laid out vertically?

Tags: html, css

Does the "div#wraper" create a BFC for its descendants?

```
<div id="wraper"  style="overflow:visible">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
<div>
```

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

The 'overflow' of the "div#wraper" is 'visible', so it does not create a BFC but an inline formatting context.

However, the descendants was laid out one after the other, vertically, which meets the rule of BFC.

How to explain the contradiction, the boxes in an inline formating context was laid out vertically?

Comment: `display: visible` isn't valid css.

Comment: No, has to have an overflow value other than visible

Comment: @ Evan Trimboli Already corrected.

Comment: A vertical layout doesn't define a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). A BFC is a region in which floated elements can affect one another

Comment: @prospector But why the descendants act sa in a BFC?

Comment: @Weapon I didn't know what BFC was, had to Google it and I quoted this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: @prospector I have modified the question. My confusion is that why the boxes in an inline formating context was laid out vertically?

Comment: Note that your text says >'overflow' _other than_ 'visible'< and you have your box set **as** `visible`

Comment: @4castle A BFC generates a vertical layout and an (IFC)Inline formatting context generates a horizontal layout.Can you tell me why the "div#wraper"    generates IFC, however in which the other two "div" laid out vertically.

Comment: @Jhecht My purpose is to create an IFC)Inline formatting context explicitly.

Comment: as the link showed `overflow:visible` doesn't create a BFC

Comment: try `display:inline-block` instead

Comment: @prospector I kown "overflow:visible" doesn't create a BFC. My quetion is Why it behaves as a BFC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of your entire question is flawed. Assuming the inner divs retain their default styles, then they are block boxes, which means #wraper can't possibly establish an inline formatting context in that situation in the first place.

The inner divs participate in block layout, but they participate in whatever BFC that is already there (that #wraper itself *also* participates in). This can be from some ancestor that meets the criteria for establish a BFC; otherwise, it's the BFC of the root element.

Comment: You means the  #wraper establish a BFC in that situation?Obvious it's not.

Comment: @Weapon: It neither establishes a BFC nor an IFC.

Comment: So, the  #wraper is not a block containing box? the #wraper is not the containing block of the inner div? the containing block of the three div is the root element in this situation?

Comment: @Weapon: #wraper is a block container box and it serves as the containing block for the inner divs. But it does not establish a BFC. Not all boxes establish formatting contexts. Note that "box", "containing block" and "block formatting context" are three different things.

Comment: @Weapon: Yes. Just not one that's established by #wraper.

Comment: @BoltClock Why does the root element establish a BFC? I couldn't find that in the specs.

Comment: @jddxf: Actually, it does not - my wording was inaccurate there. The BFC in which the root element participates in is established by the initial containing block. The reason the initial containing block establishes a BFC is because *something* needs to start the ball rolling somehow.

Comment: @BoltClock I could totally understand that the initial containing block establishes a BFC. Still I couldn't find something relevant in the specs.

Comment: Hi @BoltClock I have a question about the BFC - do the flex and grid items stay in the Normal Flow? My doubt arises MAINLY because flex-direction: column stacks the flex items VERTICALLY like a Block Formatting Context does - Thanks in advance, I guess the comment doesn't really fit the question but I need someone amazing in CSS like you.

Comment: @Daniel: As far as I know the term "normal flow" does not apply to flex items and grid items as they participate in flex layout and grid layout respectively.

Comment: Correct @BoltClock, I did some research and it is as you say, the flex elements and grid elements are not in the normal flow, what IS in the normal flow is simply the flex/grid container (this because there is `display: flex;` (block-level) or `display: inline-flex;` (inline-level), the same for the grid container).